# Storing Special Characters in MySQL (Android, PHP involved too)

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Ok, I am trying to store data in a MySQL database from an Android app.  I use PHP as the go between.

What I submit to the database is this (for example):
Sakè

What is stored in MySQL is:
SakÃ¨

When I print the line back out in Android it knows to convert back to:
Sakè

The problem is, when I do certain select statements, yeah it basically doesn't work out like it should.  Is there any way I can keep this consistent?

Just a note in MySQL: I use utf8_general_ci

Comment: What do you mean you "use utf8_general_ci"? First step is to make sure the columns in your tables use the utf8 charset. Second step is what @WebnetMobile.com said, use SET NAMES utf8 to make sure the connection uses utf8 at runtime.

Comment: I set the character encoding for each table in the MySQL table.  "utf8_general_ci" is the one I have it set to.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: there are many encodings involved: db encoding, column encoding, connection encoding, display encoding. Usually you remember about setting db/table charset + display encoding (html) and assume it's all that's needed. As you can see it is not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enforce correct character for your database **connection** for your PHP scripts. Simplest approach would be to execute this query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

just once, best after you `connect()`. If you use Zend Framework, just add this:

```
resources.db.params.charset  = UTF8
```

to your application.ini. For mysqli see [set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php). If you use anything else, check the docs for something similar. If there's nothing, the `SET NAMES` trick would always work.

**One important note though** - depending on how you put your data to the DB, your database content most likely require fixing as it is corrupted by broken charset during `INSERT`s. So if even you do `SET NAMES` now, you most likely still see **old** data shown wrong. But that is, ironically, OK - you are now showing all fine, but data itself is broken. You just now need to fix your data (just re-insert it).

Comment: Ok, doing a Google search on that, that is exactly what I need.  Can I ask an additional question?  Where do you put this?  in PHP script (I don't use Zend).  Where in the script?  For each script that I use to insert data? Edit:  I see you did touch on that - just after I connect.  So probably in my includes file I have on top of all of my scripts then...

Comment: Basically if you do not use any class to simplify DB access, then call it once, just after `mysqli_connect()`: `mysqli_connect(); mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8');`. Of course you need to check if `connect()` was successful prior doing query. If you use any class, add that query to next to the connect() handling code.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: see edited answer to avoid thinking solution "does not work" :)

Comment: It's a small project, so no classes here.  Thanks.  That did fix inserting data... now I just have to figure out how to read it back to the app (but that wasn't really the question so marked you correct!)

Comment: In response to your edit, I cleaned out old data already so that's handled, but thanks!  Now when I read it back from PHP to Android it shows up as Null....